# Where can I find app.master?

Tags: office-365

I want to use `app.master` that should be located at: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL`

But the GLOBAL folder is missing. Where can I find app.master?

Comment: You have tagged your question with `Office 365`. Are you sure even after installing `Client Namespaces` you will get this Global Folder. May be your question is relevant to On Premise